# C# LINQ multiple arrays to simple list of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array of objects `List<SlovnikWords>`, here is the model:

```
class SlovnikWord
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Word> Forms { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And the model for `Word` is as follows

```
class Word
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = -1;
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I need to create a list of all the `Forms` from all the original list of `SlovnikWords`, here's what I came up with:

```
var q = SlovnikData.Select(x => x.Forms);
```

This unfortunately creates an array of arrays, where as I only need one dimensional array of `Forms` without the outer one, i.e. a compound of `x.Forms`, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

`var q = SlovnikData.SelectMany(x => x.Forms);`